# FTP file upload Android Studio

Tags: java, android, ftp

so I am developing an app to take in a file and upload it to an FTP server, but i keep getting android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. Any ideas on how to fix this?
This is my code

```
    public void sendData() throws Exception {
       FTPUploader stuff = new FTPUploader("xxx","xxx","xxx");
       stuff.doInBackground();
    }
```

FTPUploader Class:

```
    import android.os.AsyncTask;

    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.InetAddress;

    public class FTPUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        //@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
            try {

               con.connect(InetAddress.getByName(params[0]));

                if (con.login(params[1], params[2])) {
                    con.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    String data = params[3];
                    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
                    boolean result = con.storeFile(params[4], in);
                    in.close();
                    if (result) {
                        System.out.println("upload result: " + result);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call from your main activity or class instead of doInBackground ()

new FTPUploader().execute(param1,param2,param3);